# how to make a slider with restricted values using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, slider

I'm trying to make a slider that has restricted values, starting from 0,5,30,50,70,90,"unlimited".
The slider must jump from 0 to the other values ,so I can't use "steps".

This is how it should look like :

O===================================>

0
         5
         30
         50
         70
         90
      unlimited

Jumping from a value to another

The fact that I have to change the steps value from 0 to 5 and change it again from 5 to 30 is where I crashed.

I found one example using MUI but I can't use it.

Comment: You are looking for range sliders.
Check this documentation out:  **[How To Create Range Sliders](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)**

In the documentation there are various examples of sliders with JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.